# Multiple scala data frame concat

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql

I have Multiple dfs that I want to combine them into 1 big df

```
+----+----------+----------+
|year|   state  |     count|
+----+----------+----------+
|2014|        CT|    343477|
|2014|        DE|    123431|
|2014|        MD|    558686|
|2014|        NJ|    773321|
|2015|        CT|    343477|
|2015|        DE|    123431|
|2015|        MD|    558686|
|2015|        NJ|    773321|
|2016|        CT|    343477|
|2016|        DE|    123431|
|2016|        MD|    558686|
|2016|        NJ|    773321|
|2017|        CT|    343477|
|2017|        DE|    123431|
|2017|        MD|    558686|
|2017|        NJ|    773321|
+----+----------+----------+
+-----------------+
|count_2          |
-----------------+
|           343477|
|           123431|
|           558686|
|           773321|
|           343477|
|           123431|
|           558686|
|           773321|
|           343477|
|           123431|
|           558686|
|           773321|
|           343477|
|           123431|
|           558686|
|           773321|
+-----------------+
```

I want to combine them into 1 df

```
        +----+----------+----------+--------------------
        |year|   state  |     count| count_2
        +----+----------+----------+--------------------
        |2014|        CT|    343477|343477
        |2014|        DE|    123431|123431
        |2014|        MD|    558686|558686
        |2014|        NJ|    773321|773321
        |2015|        CT|    343477|343477
        |2015|        DE|    123431|123431
        |2015|        MD|    558686|558686
        |2015|        NJ|    773321|773321
        |2016|        CT|    343477|343477
        so on...
```

I used sql() but it didn't work.. I also tried to join df (left join) it is also not working, what kind of join would this be without duplicate?
Thanks!

Comment: If `count_1` and `count_2` are identical, and the second DF only has `count_2` - what's the value in joining them? It's just like duplicating `count_1`. If that's not the case, please edit the post to show a clearer example.

Comment: I didn’t print out the year and state, but two dfs are identical except the count names. The first one is count-1 second one is count_2

Comment: Are they identical in their values as well as the column names? Again, it's unclear what value you're getting from this join/concat - given the desired output there's no added information coming in from the second DF, please clarify.

Comment: Yes they are identical in their values as well, except the name of the count .. so df1 has a count_1 name and df2 has count_2 .. but their values are exactly same

Comment: So you can just use `df1.withColumn("count_2", $"count")` - duplicate `count` column with a new name. No need for `df2`...

Comment: no, I can't do that, these dfs are derived from a trunk of parquet files, for those I have tested they have all correct values(which they are supposed to be same) if there is an issue with the parquet file (say the count is not the same, then this df1.withColumn() will miss the miscount issue...

Comment: Next time, please include this information in the post - this is critical to show in the sample data too (e.g. for a line missing in one of the DFs - what should be the expected result? It's impossible to give the know answer without this information).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, there is no shortcut for your problem. Please find my below solution

```
//Inputs: 
val df1=Seq((2014,"CT",343477),(2014,"DE",123431),(2014,"MD",558686),(2014,"NJ",773321),(2015,"CT",343477),(2015,"DE",123431),(2015,"MD",558686),(2015,"NJ",773321)).toDF("year","state","count")

val df2=Seq(343477,123431,558686,773321,343477,123431,558686,773321).toDF("count_2")

//Solution: 

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
val winFun=Window.partitionBy("year","state","count").orderBy("year")
df1.join(df2,df1("count")===df2("count_2")).withColumn("row_no",row_number over winFun).filter("row_no =1").drop("row_no").orderBy("year").show
```

Sample Output:

```
+----+-----+------+-------+
|year|state| count|count_2|
+----+-----+------+-------+
|2014|   DE|123431| 123431|
|2014|   MD|558686| 558686|
|2014|   CT|343477| 343477|
|2014|   NJ|773321| 773321|
|2015|   MD|558686| 558686|
|2015|   DE|123431| 123431|
|2015|   CT|343477| 343477|
|2015|   NJ|773321| 773321|
+----+-----+------+-------+
```

Comment: tested your code, it worked in my case, thank you so much, if I need to added more dfs(same as df1 and df2) do I just added it as df3,df2,df1("count")===df2("count_2")===df3("count_3") ?

Comment: You need to do like this ans=df1 and df2 then again ans=ans and df3 one by one.

Comment: Way in which you are thinking that will also work. You need to do like df1.join(df2,df1("count")===df2("count_2")).join(df3,df1("count")===df3("count_3"))....withCOlumn.filter.drop

Comment: I am not sure what the message means?

Comment: sub_df1.join(sub_df2,sub_df1("base_count")===sub_df2("lineaverage_count")).join(sub_df3,sub_df1("base_count")===sub_df3("lineaverage_count")).withColumn("row_no",row_number over winFun).filter("row_no =1").drop("row_no").orderBy("year").show
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Cannot resolve column name "lineaverage_count" among (RATIO_count); what did I do wrong?

Comment: Please check column name carefully. Also this was my thinking but I never did it. I think it is possible I have to test it.